# How to add php to theme to show alt attributes

Tags: images, templates

I am trying to figure out how to add PHP / code to my template so that my alt tags show up for my images. The theme has been modified by a company that is no longer around so I can't ask how to rectify this.

This is the code that the theme developer gave me but it doesn't correspond to a file that came with the theme.

```
<?php echo '<img src="' . $src[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />'; ?>
```

I suppose my question is how do I make this work so my alt tags show up.

This is the website https://www.emabarkboathire.com.au and this is the main alterer pages. https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/ 
https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/galaxy/

I don't have any PHP experience but know my way around Wordpress ok.

Any help will be very gratefully received.

Thanks

Danny

```
<div class="ycbe-gallery ycbe-new">
    <span class="ycbe-new-to-upload"><?php _e( 'To be uploaded on save:', 'yachtcharter' ); ?></span>
    <br clear="all">
</div>

<div class="ycbe-gallery ycbe-add-attachments">
    <a id="ycbe-add-attachments" class="ycbe-add-attachments"><?php _e( 'Add to gallery', 'yachtcharter' ); ?></a>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="ycbe_gallery_hidden" id="ycbe-gallery-hidden" value="<?php echo $value; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        var _custom_media = true,
        _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        $( '#ycbe-add-attachments' ).click( function( e ) {
            var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
            var button = $(this);
            var id = button.attr( 'class' ).replace( '_button', '' );
            _custom_media = true;
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function( props, attachment ){
                if ( _custom_media ) {
                    if( attachment.type == 'image' && attachment.subtype !== 'svg+xml' ) {
                        if($( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val() == '') {
                            $( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val(attachment.id);
                        } else {
                            oldVal = $( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val();
                            $( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val( oldVal + ',' + attachment.id );
                        }
                        var src = attachment.sizes.thumbnail.url;
                        $( '.ycbe-gallery.ycbe-new' ).show();
                        $( '.ycbe-gallery.ycbe-new span' ).after( '<div class="ycbe-attachment"><img width="64" height="64" src="' + src + '" data-id="' + attachment.id + '" class="ycbe-attached-file ycbe-image" /><a class="ycbe-remove-attachment" data-id="' + attachment.id + '">Remove</a></div>' );
                    }
                } else {
                    return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
                };
            }
            wp.media.editor.open(button);
            return false;

        });

        $( '.add_media' ).on( 'click', function() {
            _custom_media = false;
        });

        $( '.ycbe-remove-attachment' ).live( 'click', function() {
            if( confirm( 'Are you sure you want to remove this attachment?' ) ) {
                valArr = $( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val().split( ',' );
                var index = valArr.indexOf( $( this ).attr( 'data-id' ) );
                if ( index > -1 ) {
                    valArr.splice( index, 1 );
                    $( this ).parent().remove();
                }
                $( '#ycbe-gallery-hidden' ).val( valArr.toString() );
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry the links didint work. 

https://www.embarkboathire.com.au

https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/

https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/galaxy/

Comment: There's not enough information in the question to give an answer. What is the full code from the template for displaying the image, including the stuff around it?

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me. This is the code from the uncustomised theme that the theme developer sent me. 

<?php echo '<img src="' . $src[0] . '" alt="' . get_the_title() . '" />'; ?>

This is a link code from the modified plugin code. Not sure how much of it was required so i saved it all.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/010vp1v4pcmk6nx/yacht-modified-php.rtf?dl=0

Many thanks

Danny

Comment: It looks like that entire layout is being displayed using WP Bakerys Visual Composer plugin. Additionally, the link to the code you gave leads to a screenshot, and it's only the root file that loads the other files. I'd guess is probably it  `includes/shortcode/boat_page.php` but I couldn't tell.

Comment: Hi Tom i have all the PHP for boat_page.php not sure how i post it so you can see it? Is it just copy and paste into the comments?

Thanks

Danny

Comment: I have added the code to the first question

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these codes to your theme's `function.php` file:

```
function isa_add_img_title( $attr, $attachment = null ) {

    $img_title = trim( strip_tags( $attachment->post_title ) );

    $attr['title'] = $img_title;
    $attr['alt'] = $img_title;

    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes','isa_add_img_title', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: HI, I tried adding the above code to function.php and it didnt work i am afraid. 

thanks

Danny

Comment: Hi so having looked into it more the image is the featured image on the boats.php page and its then being turned into a thumbnail. I have been looking through the code and there is thumbnail code and featured image code. Not sure which one needs to be altered. 

Thanks

Danny