# Alt Tags Missing from code

Tags: images

I have tracked down the code that is missing the alt tag not sure how to add it or where to add the code. All of the images have the tags just not showing up.

```
</div>
<div id="page-header" style="background:url(https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/sydney-harbour-clear.jpg) top center;">
<div class="page-header-inner">
<div class="page-header-inner-box">
<h1>Sydney Boat Hire</h1>
<div class="title-block3"></div>
<p><span><a href="https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/"><span>Home</span></a></span> <span class="sep"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span> <span class="current">Sydney Boat Hire</span></p> </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="content-wrapper  clearfix">

<div class="main-content">
<div class="wpb_row vc_row-fluid content-wrapper content-wrapper-standard clearfix   " style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; "><div class="col span_12"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner "><div class="wpb_wrapper">
<div class="yacht-listing-wrapper-3 clearfix">
<div class="yacht-block">
<div class="yacht-block-image">
**<a href="https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/zephyr/"><img src="https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/zephyr-boat10-300x185.jpg" /></a>**
</div>
<div class="yacht-block-content">
<h3><a href="https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/zephyr/">Zephyr</a></h3>
<p class="element-excerpt"></p> <div class="title-block5"></div>
<ul>
<li><span class="element-capacity">Total Capacity: <strong>30</strong></span></li><li><span class="element-price-from">Price P/H From: <strong>$550</strong></span></li> </ul>
<a class="seeMoreButton" href="https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/zephyr/">See More</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks

Danny

Comment: Hello! Can you edit your question and provide some context? It's not clear what you're asking, just that there are `alt` tags missing, but no indications of where or why, or how the HTML fragment in your question is generated, and no PHP code. Also, I'm seeing html classes starting with `vc_`, is this visual composer output?

Comment: It looks like this is related to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/318882/how-to-add-php-to-theme-to-show-alt-attributes, Without seeing the code that generates that output it's not possible to answer the question, and any answer you get will be a technical one that will require at minimum a beginner level understanding of PHP.  I'm going to close this as a duplicate, and use your original question

Comment: Hi Tom 

Thanks for getting in contact. The page itself is where the boats are loaded is https://www.embarkboathire.com.au/boats/ 

As for the PHP code. I am trying to figure out if it's in the plugin or in the theme.

Don't want to just paste loads of code that might not be relevant. 

Thanks again

Danny